# WooCommerce - Member Preference Category selection in Profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want my website to have Member Preference Category selection in Profile page of a WooCommerce based Webiste. (i.e) My website is based on Food Delivering, and has category like Non-Veg, Vegan, Full pack etc. If the member logged into the site, It should ask preference that which category you want to show for future. If I'm a Vegan and if i select Vegan category. Next Time when i logged in It will Show only Vegan Category.
Is it Possible in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution using Sessions WC()->session->set(), WC()->session->get( ) in account details page and made necessary changes in nav-menu.php